# how to handle bytestream data in c socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp

```
void *rtp_rec()
{
    memset(rtpbuf, 0, sizeof(rtpbuf));
    unsigned char rtpbuf[2024]="";
    while(1)
    {
        receive = recvfrom(sock1, rtpbuf,sizeof(rtpbuf) ,0,(struct sockaddr*)&serverrtp,(socklen_t*)&sizeof(serverrtp););
        n = sendto(sock2,rtpbuf,strlen(rtpbuf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&sendtoother,sizeof(sendtoother));
    }
    return 0;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

1. I am receiving 180 byte data packet continuosly (byte by byte) in `rtpbuf(buffer)` using `recvfrom()` on socket (sock1).
2. and I want to send same data packet of 180 byte to another
   socket (sock2) using `sendto()`.

But my `sendto()` function sending 1 byte data packet, `recvfrom()` also receving data byte by byte.

Please suggest some logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of `recvfrom()` to make sure there was no error, and to ensure you received the proper number of bytes.  Also, you probably want to send as many bytes as you're receiving rather than using `strlen(rtpbuf)` just in case you have null bytes in the received data.

```
receive = recvfrom(sock1, rtpbuf,sizeof(rtpbuf) ,0,(struct sockaddr*)&serverrtp,(socklen_t*)&sizeof(serverrtp));
if (receive == -1) {
    perror("recvfrom failed");
} else {
    printf("received %d bytes\n", receive);
    n = sendto(sock2,rtpbuf,receive,0,(struct sockaddr *)&sendtoother,sizeof(sendtoother));
}
```